# compare 2 value from cell and change cell color in JTable

Tags: java, jtable

So i want to compare 2 value from 2 cells on the same row ("Initial Target" and "Result Target") from my table, and if the value is not the same the cell on "Result Target" column will turn red
, but  my code turn all cell to red, here's the result :

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWIqE.png)

here's what i expect :

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0kYF.png)

here's my code :

```
tblResult = new JTable(tableModel) {
        @Override
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col) {
            Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
            Object value1 = getModel().getValueAt(row, 2);
            Object value2 = getModel().getValueAt(row, 1);
            if (value1!=value2) {
                    comp.setBackground(Color.red);
            }
             else {
                comp.setBackground(Color.white);
            }
            return comp;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing `if (value1 != value2)` you are just checking whether `value1` and `value2` have the same reference and here they don't so, this comparison will always return `true`.

What you can do instead is cast these objects to String or Integer like this:

```
String value1 = (String) getModel().getValueAt(row, 2);
String value2 = (String) getModel().getValueAt(row, 1);
```

And then perform the comparison as follows:

```
if (!value1.equalsIgnoreCase(value2)) {}
```

Comment: woow it works, but its still all cells in row to red, i just want the cell on 3rd column turn to red, here's the result: [result](http://i.imgur.com/uJNiAnl.png)

Comment: @Wallflower Sorry, I'm not sure how you are setting the color because I see `Color.white` in both `if` as well as `else` condition. You might have to check this logic again.

Comment: i've found the solution just add 'if (!value1.equalsIgnoreCase(value2) && col==2)'

Answer (score 1):

You execute the logic for each columnIndex, so each rendering component has its color manipulated and is painted e.g. red. You should have some condition around like `if(col == 2)` and so only execute your color magic when the method `prepareRenderer()` is called for the 3rd column.

Of cause the already mentioned comparison fix `if (!value1.equalsIgnoreCase(value2)) {}`should be done.

By the way, you might use `table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(TableCellRenderer)` to set a specific rendering logic just for this column.